# Load file with relative path

Tags: scheme, chez-scheme

With chezscheme to load files within the current directory `all-codes`

```
(load "ch4-mceval.scm")
```

However, if change directory to the parent-dir and try:

```
(load "all-codes/ch4-mceval.scm")
```

Exception in load: failed for all-codes/ch4-mceval.scm: no such file or directory:

My directory displays like

```
$ tree -L 2                                                                   
.                                                                             
├── 00.elisp-SICP.org                                                         
├── 00.preface.org                                                                                            
├── 01.building-abstrations-with-procedures.org                               
├── 02.building-abstrations-with-data.org
├── 03.modularity-objects-and-states.org
├── 04.metalinguistic-abstration.org
├── 05.computing-with-register-machines.org
├── all-codes
│   ├── ch1.scm
│   ├── ch2.scm
│   ├── ch2support.scm
│   ├── ch2tests.scm
│   ├── ch3.scm
```

How could I load the scm codes from 'all-codes' with the current level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should either use an absolute path for the file or use `source-directories` to redefine the set of directories searched for source or object files when a file is loaded via load.

More here:

> **procedure: (load path)** ... The parameter `source-directories` (Section
>   12.5) determines the set of directories searched for source files not identified by absolute path names.

(source http://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/csug9.5/system.html#./system:h4)

and here

> **global parameter: source-directories**
>
> ... determines the set of directories searched for source or object
>   files when a file is loaded via `load`, `load-library`, `load-program`,
>   `include`, `visit`, or `revisit`, when a syntax error occurs, or when a
>   source file is opened in the interactive inspector.
>
> The default value is the list (".")...

(source http://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/csug9.5/system.html#g114)